# Why does OnCalcFields Trigger fire in GUI moving up or down

Tags: delphi, ado, dbgrid

how can I stop 'onCalcFields' Trigger to fire when I Reach for 1st Record or Last Record
while I set 'MyQuery.Prpertie' ('AutoCalcFeilds' = False)

Comment: Set the OnCalcs handler to nil, then set it back when you need it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If AutoCalcFields=FALSE then presumably onCalcFields will trigger whenever a result needs to be calculated. So why do you need to disable it on special occasions? Instead you should, if necessary, deal with the special occasions within the OnCalcFields event.